# How to normalize Euclidean distance over two vectors?

Tags: machine-learning, normal-distribution, clustering, normalization

**Why I want to normalize Euclidean distance**

Currently, I am designing a ranking system, it weights between Euclidean distance and several other distances.

Euclidean distance behaves unbounded, that is, it outputs any $value > 0$ , while other metrics are within range of $[0, 1]$. Have to come up with a function to squash Euclidean to a value between 0 and 1.

**What does my data look like**

Euclidean distance is computed by `sklearn`, specifically, `pairwise_distances`.

This function takes two inputs: `v1` and `v2`, where $v_1, v_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{1200}$ and $||v_1|| = 1 , ||v_2||=1$ (L2-norm).

**My simple method:**

Derive the bounds of Eucldiean distance:

$\begin{align*}
  (v_1 - v_2)^2 &= v_1^T v_1 - 2v_1^T v_2 + v_2^Tv_2\\
                &=2-2v_1^T v_2 \\
                &=2-2\cos \theta
\end{align*}$

thus, the Euclidean is a $value \in [0, 2]$.

to normalize, just simply apply $new_{eucl} = euclidean/2$. Would it be a valid transformation?

**Suggestions from other people**

As some of people suggest me to try Gaussian, I am not sure what they mean, more precisely I am not sure how to compute variance (data is too big takes over 80G storing space, compute actual variance is too costly). More importantly, I am very confused why need Gaussian here?

**Edited**

As an extension, suppose the vectors are not normalized to have norm eqauls to 1. What do we do to normalize the Euclidean distance?

Comment: Euclidean distance on L2-normalized vectors is called chord distance. It is a chord in the unit-radius circumference. Its maximum is 2, the diameter. Dividing euclidean distance by a positive constant is valid, it doesn't change its properties.

Comment: The question is whether you really want Euclidean distance, why not Manhattan? Have a look on Gower similarity (search the site).

Comment: what do you think of the answers here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/136232/definition-of-normalized-euclidean-distance ?

Answer (score 1):

If you only allow **non-negative** vectors, the maximum distance is sqrt(2). For example, (1,0) and (0,1). You can only achieve larger values if you use negative values, and 2 is achievable only by v and -v.

You should also consider to use thresholds. The difference between 1.1 and 1.0 probably does not matter.

Then you can simply use min(euclidean, 1.0) to bound it by 1.0.