# accuracy of a regression prediction model

Tags: regression, prediction, accuracy

I developed two prediction models using non-linear regression analysis to predict a set of values using sigmoidal and power functions. I was wondering how I can evaluate the accuracy of these individual models (Sigmoid predictions vs Power predictions) besides RMSE? Also, are there any other hypothesis tests such as Chi-Square Goodness of Fit Test that I can use to evaluate the prediction accuracy of these models?

Comment: check this for normalized eucledian similarity as a candidate measure: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/136232/definition-of-normalized-euclidean-distance

Answer (score 3):

There are many measures of point prediction accuracy, like the [mae](/questions/tagged/mae), the [rmse](/questions/tagged/rmse), or the [mape](/questions/tagged/mape). You may want to browse through our questions with these tags. [Why use a certain measure of forecast error (e.g. MAD) as opposed to another (e.g. MSE)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/45875/1352) is likely helpful, as may be [What are the shortcomings of the Mean Absolute Percentage Error (MAPE)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/299712/1352) and [Mean absolute error OR root mean squared error?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/48267/1352)

[This page and discusses some of these KPIs](https://otexts.com/fpp2/accuracy.html) in the context of time series forecasting.

Answer (score 0):

You can evaluate the accuracy of a regression model (including nonlinear ones) by comparing the predicted values to the actual values. I'd say the best way to do this is graphically with e.g. boxplots of the residuals, a scatterplot of actual vs. predicted values, a quantile quantile plot of those and a Tukey mean difference plot.

You can also look at the values of the residuals numerically and see if any are unacceptable large.

Answer (score 0):

check this for normalized eucledian similarity as a candidate measure: [Definition of normalized Euclidean distance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/136232/definition-of-normalized-euclidean-distance)

The answers already have great details!